# Java, Should I use switch-case or if-else within a switch-case?

Tags: java, function, if-statement, switch-statement

This program copies a string (a password) on the clipboard, and I want to add the option to copy a username as well. So if a user forgets his/her username on an online account (or is just lazy), it is possible to get that as well.

First the user chooses the game/whatever, then the user gets to choose what gets copied to the clipboard: the username or the password. So do I add another `switch-case` under all those options, or do I go with an `if-statement`? Should I put a function call under each of those?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package helloworldapp;

/**
 *
 * @author Au-Thor
 */
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class HelloWorldApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int n = 1;
       String addedString = "replace"; //This is for later usage
       String titleNames[] = {"Planetside 2","Nasty Website","Useless Social Media Account","Someother"};
       Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
       String thePassword = "Nothing";

       System.out.println("Enter a key: "); //This is for later usage
       addedString=(userInput1.nextLine()); //This is for later usage

    while(n!=0){ 
        Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in

        for(int i = 0; i < titleNames.length; i++){  //Menu print-out
            int h=i+1;
            System.out.println( "["+h+".] " + titleNames[i]); 
        }

        System.out.println( "\n[0.] Quit\n");         
        System.out.println("\nEnter a number: ");
        n = userChoice.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.

        switch (n) {
            case 1:  //Ask if the user wants the username or the password
                     thePassword = "MAD PASSWORD FOR MY ACCOUNT" ;
                     break;
            case 2:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 3:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 4:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 5:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 6:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 7:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 8:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 9:  thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 10: thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 11: thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 12: thePassword = "Replace";
                     break;
            case 0:
                break;
            default: System.out.println("\nOption does not exist");;
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println("Current: " +thePassword+"\n"); //Change this to the Page or Game the credentials are for

        String myString = thePassword;
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
        Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        }

    System.out.println("Quitting..");
    }    
}
```

Extra stuff:
Is there something that could be done more efficiently (besides all of it :D)? Should I use more functions? Can I use a function to produce a `switch-case` structure that scales to the parameters given to it, to create all the switch cases with the same function, is that even possible?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself using really long if/then/else or long switch statements as yourself if it makes more sense to do in a loop. And if your data changes a lot maybe save the options in a config file and load it into an array or something so you can change the data without recompiling.

Comment: The index 'n' to your switch statement, in this case, which is non-sparse, meaning there aren't gaps, might as well be an index directly into an array of strings and forget the if/then/else or switch.

Comment: Oh you mean like: `thePassword = passwords[userChoice];` type of thing? That makes a lot of sense, and makes stuff much easier when I expand this.
 
Loading information from a file is something I haven't done much yet, but I am about to expand this to that direction.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.  A lot of stuff to get used to but you will start to think about optimization and get tricks up yours sleeve about how to approach things like this and it will get easier and more natural.

Comment: Many thanks. That solves my problem, I'll just make a 2-dimensional array to store the login information, I think that's the way to go for the time being, then for the next step I'll see if I can make the file-reading bit to work. Too bad I can't upvote a comment, nor can I upvote anything at this point(visibly at least); too low rep.

Answer (score 0):

On your switch statement you could try use something like this:

```
switch (n) {
        case 1:  //Ask if the user wants the username or the password
                 thePassword = "MAD PASSWORD FOR MY ACCOUNT" ;
                 break;
        case 2:                       
        case 3:  
        case 4:  
        case 5:  
        case 6:  
        case 7: 
        case 8:  
        case 9:  
        case 10: 
        case 11: 
        case 12: thePassword = "Replace";
                 break;
        case 0:
            break;
        default: System.out.println("\nOption does not exist");;
                 break;
    }
```

Is not mandatory to use `break` on every `case` if they are going to have the same behavior.

Comment: Alright, nice to know, though I'm about fill each of those with different stuff, the repetition was due to copypasting. But still, that will very likely become useful knowledge in the future.